# Apache POI - Not implemented error with CONCAT function

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to edit a excel document that contains formulas, the editing works fine but the formulas don't update.

I'm trying to use the following code to get it to evaluate the formulas, however i get an error

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    for (Row r : sheet) {
        for (Cell c : r) {
            evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);
        }
    }
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: Error evaluating cell Sheet1!C17
> at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.addExceptionInfo(WorkbookEvaluator.java:344)
> at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:285)
> at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:216)
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:56)
> at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:185)
> at Timetable.ExcelAPI.calculateFormula(ExcelAPI.java:139)

Cell C17 has the following formula.

```
=IF(C3="","",CONCAT($A17,$B17,C3,$B17,$A$16))
```

I've also tried

```
=IF(C3="","",CONCATENATE($A17,$B17,C3,$B17,$A$16))
```

If i programmatically create the formula it works

```
cell.setCellFormula("IF(C3=\"\",\"\",CONCAT($A17,$B17,C" + (start + 1) + ",$B17,$A$16))");
```

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? [The latest version has the relevant function implemented](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/TextFunction.html#CONCATENATE)

Comment: compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.0"

Comment: Try with 5.0, which was released a few months ago?

Comment: Nope, same error

Comment: I've been able to get it to work if i programatically create the formula, but i don't want that in the end. cell.setCellFormula("IF(C3=\"\",\"\",CONCAT($A17,$B17,C" + (start + 1) + ",$B17,$A$16))");

Comment: If you read one of the problematic formulas back with Apache POI, what does POI think Excel stuffed into the file? I'm wondering if Excel is doing something odd with how it encodes the formula, as there shouldn't be a difference

Comment: How would I go about doing that>

Comment: Fetch the cell in question, then print out [Cell.getCellFormula](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellFormula--)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by changing the call to the function to simply

```
workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `Excel` function support of `apache poi` is at `Excel 2007` standard, `CONCATENATE` is implemented but `CONCAT` is not. Furthermore functions which are introduced after `Excel 2007` are prefixed with `_xlfn.`.

So your full stacktrace should contain:

```
...
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: _xlfn.CONCAT
...
```

A work around could be replacing "_xlfn.CONCAT" by "CONCATENATE" in formulas before evaluating.

Following code works for me and evaluates `CONCATENATE` as well as `CONCAT` formulas.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcel {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExampleConcatenate.xlsx"));
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();  
 
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA && cell.getCellFormula().contains("_xlfn.CONCAT")) {
     cell.setCellFormula(cell.getCellFormula().replace("_xlfn.CONCAT", "CONCATENATE")); 
    }
    String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
    System.out.println(value);
   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Why then changing the formula in excel to CONCATENATE didn't work, even though its supposed to be supported?

Comment: @Ceri Turner: Cannot reproduce that issue. For me formulas using `CONCATENATE` get evaluated. Can you uploade a `Excel` example having formulas using `CONCATENATE` which not get evaluated?

Comment: `CONCAT` supports areas/ranges which `CONCATENATE` doesn't, though upgrading to Apache POI 5.0.1 once released will be the ultimate fix since that has `CONCAT` implemented in it :)

Answer (score 1):

Good news - the `CONCAT` function is now supported! Bad news - not in your version...

If you upgrade (once available) to Apache POI 5.0.1 or later, the `CONCAT` function is now supported, see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65185

If you're impatient and want to backport the missing function, it's http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1887656